# Delete data from custom table when deleting a post

Tags: plugins, posts, plugin-development, wp-query, customization

I want to delete post id form my custom table, when deleting a post. I have tried this way, nothing happened. Please help.

```
add_action('delete_post', 'delete_data');

function delete_data($post_id) {
   global $wpdb;
   $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'post_order';
   if ($wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM $table_name WHERE `pid` = %d", $post_id))) {
       $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("DELETE FROM $table_name WHERE `pid` = %d", $post_id));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`delete_post` fires when the post is deleted permanently, *not* when it is trashed. I don't know if that is relevant but keep that in mind. That is the only real WordPress specific part of this question. The rest is bad PHP.

[Variables *do not expand* inside single quotes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single). You are a sending a query to the database that literally looks like

```
SELECT `id` FROM $table_name WHERE `pid` = XxX
```

What you want is either

```
$wpdb->prepare('SELECT `id` FROM '.$table_name.' WHERE `pid` = %d', $post_id)
```

Or

```
$wpdb->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM {$table_name} WHERE `pid` = %d", $post_id)
```

To run the function when you trash the post, you probably want the one or more of the [status transition hooks](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions). But a word or caution: if you delete from your table on post "trash" you can't reverse it. The "restore" function will fail to work correctly on these posts.

Comment: Yes bro, you got my problem. When i clear trash, delete_ post fires and delete operation succeed for my table. But I want to delete post id immediately from my db table when deleting the post. Thrash is not my headache.And i am aware about single quote & double quote :). It was a typo mistake